# Enabling start at login with App Sandbox enabled

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, sandbox

I have an application that must be sandboxed.

It's not a difficult task, but I see that I cannot enable automatic start at login with `LSSharedFileList` editing the Session Login Items list.

Is there another way to enable start at login with App Sandbox enabled?

Comment: Well I have found a way to launch my sandboxed application following [this tutorial](http://www.delitestudio.com/2011/10/25/start-dockless-apps-at-login-with-app-sandbox-enabled/).

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I am now going through this tutorial. I don't understand the part about adding the helper project to the existing project. How do I do this? Do I have to create a new Xcode workspace and add both projects to it, or do I drag the helper project within the main project, thus becoming a "subproject" (i.e. it is shown within the main project in the document tree)? Thank you!

Comment: The second one, the helper application is a project on its own and you have to add it to the main project as subproject dragging it.

Comment: I'm having a problem where the helper app will not build. Inside the main app bundle, the helper app is just a .xcodeproj, etc. No built .app file. Plus, the helper app is red in XCode. How do I build the helper app?

Comment: Make sure your helper application is under "Target Dependencies" in "Build Phases" of your main target.

Comment: I appreciate the help. When I click the plus button under "Target Dependencies", it says "No filter results" or "No items are available", so I can't add it?

Comment: Very precise tutorial available on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mmWEHUgEBo

Answer (score 7):

An updated project/tutorial is available here, with addendums for some misleading Console messages you'll see under 10.8.2:

http://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/

I'm not the author, but the tutorial was very helpful in getting a start-at-login app configured under 10.8.2 w/ Sandboxing enabled.

Answer (score 6):

[Apple says:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html)

> Creating a Login Item for Your App
>   To create a login item for your sandboxed app, use the `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` function (declared in `ServiceManagement/SMLoginItem.h`) as described in [“Adding Login Items Using the Service Management Framework”](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW5-SW1) in [Daemons and Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i).
>
> (With App Sandbox, you cannot create a login item using functions in the `LSSharedFileList.h` header file. For example, you cannot use the function `LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL`. Nor can you manipulate the state of launch services, such as by using the function `LSRegisterURL`.)

Comment: Yes, but you still have `Open at Login` feature in your apps and you can implement this feature in different way.