# How to add a sandboxed app to the login items

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, sandbox

I want my app to auto start if the user select the option. The methods I have been using is not allowed anymore in sandboxed apps.

I know I have to create a helper to achieve that? Is there a simple tutorial with sample code to active that?

I found this tutorial, but it does not work for me: http://www.delitestudio.com/2011/10/25/start-dockless-apps-at-login-with-app-sandbox-enabled/

It is a pretty standard thing to do, I don't understand why there is no example project available.

**UPDATE:**

I uploaded a sample project: http://ge.tt/6DntY4K/v/0?c

Comment: Actually I do, but why is it important?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what didn't work using the tutorial?  For example, were there still sandbox restrictions being enforced or were other error messages present?

Comment: Well, it doesn't even work when sandboxing is not enabled. It shows as if everything was fine, but nothing is started when I restart computer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a helper application for Mac App to start it on user login?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436318/how-to-create-a-helper-application-for-mac-app-to-start-it-on-user-login)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling start at login with App Sandbox enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837152/enabling-start-at-login-with-app-sandbox-enabled)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should succeed by using this (disclaimer: my) [tutorial](http://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/), sample project included.

**Update:** I've now tested the sample project you've uploaded: It works just fine with me, without any modifications, and launch at login succeeds. The only trick is that the AutoStart.app file has to be placed in the /Applications or ~/Applications folder to be launched successfully at login. This is necessary regardless of whether the app is sandboxed or not. However, there's no official documentation on this, I'm afraid.

Comment: Your solution works, mine doesn't on my machine for some reason. Great tutorial, Thanks!

Comment: This tutorial is awesome. However, is there a way to also add the item to the Login Items for the user in System Preferences? As of right now, its not there. I know that this is possible because I do have a couple other apps from MAS that are able to do this.

Comment: You can do that by using the (poorly documented) methods inside the LSSharedFileList API, which is part of the Launch Services. However, the API won't work when the app calling it is sandboxed: [With App Sandbox, you cannot create a login item using functions in the LSSharedFileList.h header file.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH4-SW1) MAS apps doing this will probably not be sandboxed.

Comment: Those requirements are explained in:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW29

Comment: @Tim - Your tutorial works for almost all kinds of apps but not all, probably due to an iOS bug. I am creating an app that is a menu bar app only, no windows. So I have to set `Application is Agent` to YES, to get rid of its dock icon. This will prevent the helper from launching the main app. If I set `Application is Agent` to NO, your tutorial works.

Comment: You've written a helpful article. But I have a short question. Could you please check it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47672690/best-practice-to-launch-main-app-from-the-launcher

Answer (score 11):

I've just re-done about 100 trial on [Tim's tutorial](http://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/). Finally I made it work. Although I swear it worked when I first time tried it.
In my situation is when I switch "Launch at login" to On, I can only see the helper app launched for just one second right after login. Then it was gone. 
Manually start the app, I saw the switch was turned off.

Here was what I found:

1. my bundle identifier was already in the list of
   `NSArray *running = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]`
2. the status of the `NSRunningApplication *app (bundle name equal to my app)` is:
   `[app isActive] == NO`, `[app isHidden] == NO`, `[app isTerminated] = NO`

So I made some modification to the code like:

```
BOOL alreadyRunning = NO;
BOOL isActive = NO; // my modification
NSArray *running = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
for (NSRunningApplication *app in running) {

    if ([[app bundleIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"com.mybundleidentifier"]) {
        alreadyRunning = YES;
        isActive = [app isActive]; // my modification
    }
}

if (!alreadyRunning || !isActive) { // my modification
  ....
```

Comment: My system info: Mac OS X 10.8.2, XCODE 4.6

Comment: You might want to add a `break;` just after `isActive = [app...`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `Service Management Framework`

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW5-SW1

As referenced from http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html ...

To create a login item for your sandboxed app, use the `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` function (declared in `ServiceManagement/SMLoginItem.h`) as described in `Adding Login Items Using the Service Management Framework` in Daemons and `Services Programming Guide`.

(With App Sandbox, you cannot create a login item using functions in the `LSSharedFileList.h` header file. For example, you cannot use the function `LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL`. Nor can you manipulate the state of launch services, such as by using the function `LSRegisterURL`).