# SMCopyAllJobDictionaries and SMJobCopyDictionary is deprecated, so what are their substitutions?

Tags: macos

I use `SMCopyAllJobDictionaries` and `SMJobCopyDictionary` to check whether app is Login Item in Mac, but in 10.10, they are deprecated. So what are their official recommended replacement?

Answer (score 2):

There was none yet. Quoting `ServiceManagement.h` documentation comment:

> For the specific use of testing the state of a login item that may have been
> enabled with SMLoginItemSetEnabled() in order to show that state to the
> user, this function remains the recommended API. A replacement API for this
> specific use will be provided before this function is removed.

It was deprecated without proper replacement, though still fine to use. But as revealed during WWDC22 there will be a new API called [`SMAppService`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/servicemanagement/smappservice) coming with macOS 13 Ventura.