# How can I determine if my Cocoa Desktop application is on the list of apps to be opened at login?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am developing a SandBoxed Cocoa Application. I have successfully implemented the Launch at login feature by using the Core Foundation function:

```
SMLoginItemSetEnabled
```

I have based the implementation on [This tutorial](http://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/)

But now I need a way to determine if my app is set to be launched at login, so that I can show the button in the appropriate position upon launch. I would expect a similar Core Foundation function to find out if a bundle identifier is on the list of login items, but I didn't find it.

Another problem is that, by using this Core Foundation approach, although it is recommended by Apple, my app is still inconsistent with the "Open at Login" tick in my application dock menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the functions in the LSSharedFileList.h header, which is in LaunchServices.framework, which is in CoreServices.framework.  As far as I can tell, Apple hasn't documented this stuff except in the header comments, but that's probably enough.  The basic outline is that you first create a `LSSharedFileListRef` using the function `LSSharedFileListCreate` for the list type `kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems`.  Then copy a snapshot of the list (which is a `CFArrayRef`) using `LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot`.  Then for any item in the array, you can get its URL using `LSSharedFileListItemCopyResolvedURL`.  That last function requires Mac OS X 10.10 or later, while I think the others date back to 10.5.

By the way, the docs on `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` say that it's for setting an embedded helper app as a login item, but it sounds like you're talking about a freestanding app.

[Apple's sandbox documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html) says:

> With App Sandbox, you cannot create a login item using functions in the LSSharedFileList.h header file. For example, you cannot use the function LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL.

But maybe you can still use the shared file list functions on a read-only basis.

Comment: JWWalker Thanks for your very kind answer ! the thing is, I am trying not to use any LSSharedFileList related CF functions, as I need my app to work on the Mac App Store... Thant is why although I don't need any helper app, I am following the tutorials that follow the SMLoginItemSetEnabled strategy. This brings me to two problems : I have to determine at launch if the app is among the ones that open at login, and I have to keep that setting in sync with the application dock menu item. In a few worlds, if I enable "Open at Login" in the dock, I would like my preference checkbox to update too.

Comment: @AlfonsoTesauro, I haven't submitted to the Mac App Store, so this might be a silly question, but why would using `LSSharedFileList ` APIs prevent you from using the Mac App Store?

Comment: I have read about it in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837152/enabling-start-at-login-with-app-sandbox-enabled) You can look at the yellow part to the bottom... The Apple documentation confirms that info provided... but perhaps I could use SMLoginItemSetEnabled to manage the setting, and LSSharedFileListRef to retrieve system stats about the currently enabled login items... but what I don't understand is this : Are all those ways of setting an app to be launched at login interfering with each other ? they appear to be completely different technologies...